# How to remove extra width from my website?

Tags: html, css

From 2 hours I'm looking for what error is on my page because I have a huge blank space...the width is too big and I don't want to have that space. Could you help me to fix my code ?

Here is my website where you can check : https://andrei-my-codepen.000webhostapp.com/

I don't know if it's because of an unclosed tag, or from CSS. But, when I wanted to fix this problem, I saw that, at some divs with class `row`, if I cancel `margin-left: -15px`, that space disappear, maybe is because I have too much `row` class?

[image]

**Here is my codepen : https://codepen.io/andreixfr/pen/rNNbEZE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
.site-wrap {overflow-x:hidden}
```

But this is not this ideal solution you have to keep in mind that a row in bootstrap should be wrapped in a container or container-fluid, the same with the cols that must be wrapped in a row, in your site I can see a lot of rows alone and that probably may be causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

On the CSS page, add this to the top of your code

```
body {
  position: absolute;
}
```

I tried it on your website and it works

Answer (score 1):

When applied to your rows, `margin-left: -15px` will shift these rows to the left (outside of the viewable area), so if your rows' width is set to `100%` or `100vw`, it is normal for them to leave a white space to the right.

To fix this, you should remove `margin-left: -15px`.

Or, if you really need this property, you can work around it by changing the rows' width to `width: calc(100vw + 15px)` (i.e. compensate for the eaten up 15px by adding another 15px to the row's width).

Comment: Hey, I guess I solve it by changing `margin-right: -15px` to `margin-right: 0px` and now it's working. But if I wanted to change `margin-left: -15px` didn't .

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have this:

```css
header{
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div>
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/100" />
</div>
```

The image width is set to auto by default. You want to either make the image `width: 100%`:

```css
header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/100" />
</div>
```

Or better yet, make the image a `background-image` with a `background-size: cover`:

```css
header{
   background-color: lightblue;
}

.banner{
   background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/100);
   background-size: cover;
   color: white;
   min-height: 300px;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div class="banner">
   <h1>Restaurant Caption</h1>
</div>
```

This last option is in my opinion the best, because you don't have to take any of the elements inside the banner image (like the h1 tag) outside of their normal flow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have same result :( https://imgur.com/a/dHmZhSe

Comment: @Andrew because the other elements in your banner are positioned with `absolute` and `relative`, etc. If you use a `background-image` you need to reorganize your element styles to place them correctly.

Comment: I solve it by changing `margin-right: -15px` to `margin-right: 0px` from .row, is that a good way ? Now my site is working fine.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, there's nothing wrong with that solution, as long as it doesn't break the rest of your layout